# In Retrofit- Getting NULL as Response but the results are listed in logs

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I try to GET data from the response with Retrofit but I'm getting the **null value**.
if I toast the response it is always null but the response is shown in the log but it is not
loaded into the Recyclerview

please help me this task is for Interview

**My Response Link:**
https://bikewise.org:443/api/v2/locations/markers?proximity=45.521728%2C-122.67326&proximity_square=100

**My Actuall Response**

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "title": "Stolen 2021 Specialized Sirrus 2.0 (03-14-2021)",
        "description": "<img src='https://files.bikeindex.org/uploads/Pu/408280/large_IMG_5771.JPG'>  <a target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://bikeindex.org/bikes/1018433\">View details</a>",
        "occurred_at": "2021-03-14 22:31:13 -0500",
        "marker-size": "small",
        "marker-color": "#E74C3C",
        "id": 136982
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          -122.65,
          45.51
        ]
      }
    }
```

**ApiClient Class**

```
object ApiClient {
    var BASE_URL: String = "https://bikewise.org:443/api/v2/locations/"
    val getClient: ApiInterfac
        get() {
            val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
            val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).client(client).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build()
            return retrofit.create(ApiInterfac::class.java)
        }
}
```

**ApiInterface class:**

```
    @GET("markers?proximity=45.521728%2C-122.67326&proximity_square=100")
    fun getVideoList(): Call  < DataVideos >  
}
```

**Model Class**

```
data class DataVideos(
       // @SerializedName("type")
        var listme:List<Videos>,
        @SerializedName("title")
        var title:String,
        @SerializedName("description")
        var description: String)
```

**From var listme:List below is Video Class**

```
class Videos {

    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String? = null
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String? = null
}
```

**My Data Getting fun**

```
private fun getDat1a() {
        Log.d(TAG, "GetDataFun")
        val call: Call  < DataVideos > = ApiClient .getClient.getVideoList()
        call.enqueue(object: Callback  < DataVideos > {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call  < DataVideos > ? , response : Response  < DataVideos > ? ) {
                if(response!!.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext!!,"Data:"+response!!.body()!!.listme,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                    val rst=response!!.body()
                    progerssProgressDialog.dismiss()
                    dataList.addAll(listOf(rst!!))
                    recyclerView.adapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call  < DataVideos> ? , t : Throwable ? ) {
                progerssProgressDialog.dismiss()
                Log.d(TAG, "Failes"+t)
            }
        })
    }
```

> I'm getting null in Toast as well in recyclerview but in logs i can find the data

**My Logs can show the output**

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Stolen 2021 Specialized Sirrus 2.0 (03-14-2021)","description":"\u003cimg src='https://files.bikeindex.org/uploads/Pu/408280/large_IMG_5771.JPG'\u003e  \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://bikeindex.org/bikes/1018433\"\u003eView details\u003c/a\u003e","occurred_at":"2021-03-14 22:31:13 -0500","marker-size":"small","marker-color":"#E74C3C","id":136982},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.65,45.51]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"title":"Stolen 2018 Surly Straggler (01-13-2021)","description":"\u003cimg src='https://files.bikeindex.org/uploads/Pu/144946/large_IMG_4383.jpg'\u003e Break in to my garage. \u003ca target=\"_blank\" href=\"https://bikeindex.org/bikes/516282\"\u003eView details\u003c/a\u003e","occurred_at":"2021-01-13 05:00:00 -0600","marker-size":"small","marker-color":"#EE8276","id":134325},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-122.69,45.59]}}]}
2021-03-18 09:26:45.027 7776-8035/com.lab.optisol I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- END HTTP (51772-byte body)
```

Comment: please make sure of the data class. I think its incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this model into response

```
fun getVideoList(): Call<YourResponse>   


data class YourResponse(
val type: String? = null,
val features: ArrayList<Features>? = null
)

data class Features(
val type: String? = null,
val properties: Properties? = null,
val geometry:Geometry?=null
)

class Properties(
@SerializedName("title")
@Expose
val title: String? = null,
@SerializedName("description")
@Expose
val description: String? = null,
@SerializedName("occurred_at")
@Expose
val occurred_at: String? = null,
@SerializedName("marker-size")
@Expose
val marker_size: String? = null,
@SerializedName("marker-color")
@Expose
val marker_color: String? = null,
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
val id: Int? = null

)

data class Geometry(
val type:String?=null,
val coordinates:ArrayList<Double>?=null
)
```

Comment: I Created new 'data class Features' and copied the code above but now toast is not working because of NullPointer..
i dint UnderStand This -> ```data class YourResponse( val type: String? = null, val features: ArrayList? = null )```
and how to make call fun ```fun getVideoList(): Call<YourResponse>   ```

Comment: in ```getDat1a()``` the ```val rst=response!!.body()``` is populated with the response "I'm getting values in a toast now"but I could not list it in Recyclerview can you help me?

Comment: show me your adapter and code where you set data

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataVideo` class is inappropriate to deserialize JSON into. These classes don't have the required serialized keys.

Use these classes

```
data class Response(
    @SerializedName("features")
    val features: List<Feature>?,
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String?
)

data class Feature(
    @SerializedName("geometry")
    val geometry: Geometry?,
    @SerializedName("properties")
    val properties: Properties?,
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String?
)

data class Geometry(
    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    val coordinates: List<Double>?,
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String?
)

data class Properties(
    @SerializedName("description")
    val description: String?,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int?,
    @SerializedName("marker-color")
    val markerColor: String?,
    @SerializedName("marker-size")
    val markerSize: String?,
    @SerializedName("occurred_at")
    val occurredAt: String?,
    @SerializedName("title")
    val title: String?
)
```

To generate data classes using JSON, you can use [JsonToKotlinClass](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) Android Studio Plugin

Comment: i changed my data class like below still i face same null...


```

Comment: in ```getDat1a()``` how we can get the properties?

Answer (score 0):

To Deserialize  think of it like key value pair with key being the name provided in @serializedName annotation and value to be provided in the datafield you are providing below it.

Now compare that with the models you created.

1. First of all you are not giving any @serializedName annotation to listme variable how would it know which key's value to serialize on that variable it should be having @serializedName("features") annotation.
2. In json above "features" key , we have key "type" which has a value of string so we need another variable as string with @serializedName of type .
3. Now lets see inside your Videos model class
   Where values inside features -->  List
   we dont have anything to serialize the key "type" and "properties" from json inside your model so create appropriate model and variable with same keys as in the json response as in answered by @Amit pandey

Answer (score 0):

To create proper model class
you can download Plugin  Json to Kotlin class
and when create a new class , click alt insert you will get option convert the json to kotlin class.
There you can post your json response and your model class will be created.[image: plugin]